# why my html (jquery) gives undefined variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an undefined variable issue even though I believe myself they are declared. I am trying to declare class as a variable and in this, some files are associated each other.

Error message says: `wd is not defined`.

> wd.onWebPageChange() -- in A.js

Below are the references:

```
<head>
    <!-- jQuery & jQuery UI + theme (required) -->
    <link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="A.js"></script>
    <script src="B.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
          <input name="webPage" type="text" onchange="wd.onWebPageChange()" onkeyup="wd.onWebPageChange()"/>
          <input id="getButton" type="button" value="GET" onclick="wd.onGet()"/>
</body>
```

**Update 1:**,

From `A.js`, I found below, the functions are belong to `WebDriverJsController` :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  window.wd = new WebDriverJsController();
});
```

**Tried it with**

> wd.onWebPageChange() -> `window.wd.onWebPageChange()` in the same position,

it says that `not defined or cannot get null referenced attributes`

**Update 2:** grep: wd

```
---------- BASE64-ARRAYBUFFER.JS
---------- FILESAVER.JS
---------- HAMMER.JS
---------- HAMMER.MIN.JS
---------- JQUERY-UI.CSS
---------- JQUERY-UI.JS
---------- JQUERY.JS
---------- JQUERY.KEYBOARD.JS
---------- KEYBOARD.CSS
---------- QML_VIEW_VISUALIZER.XSL

---------- WEBDRIVER-APP.JS
  window.wd = new WebDriverJsController();

---------- WEBDRIVER.JS
webdriver.AbstractBuilder.SERVER_URL_ENV = "wdurl";
webdriver.AbstractBuilder.DEFAULT_SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
webdriver.Builder.SESSION_ID_ENV = "wdsid";

---------- WEBDRIVERJSDEMO.HTML
<input name="webPage" type="text" onchange="wd.onWebPageChange()" onkeyup="wd.onWebPageChange()"/>
<input id="getButton" type="button" value="GET" onclick="wd.onGet()"/>
```

Comment: Show A.js and B.js

Comment: If in A.js and B.js you have defined the functions onWebPageChange()and onGet(), try to remove the 'wd.'

Comment: `wd` sounds like it could refer to `window`? Anyway, neither A.js nor B.js are defining `wd`, which is why you get the error.

Comment: So `wd` is undefined on global scope

Comment: jQuery and jQueryUI are different libraries, I believe `jquery-ui.css` is worthless without `jquery-ui.min.js`.

Comment: @dikkini it is such a long file, even though I roughly simplified it is over 300 lines. Do you still want to see it and would it helpful?

Comment: in your A.js, you are defining wd as a member of the window object, so you need to include the reference to the window object any time you want to call a member of wd. Basically, instead of just wd.onWebPageChange(), you need to invoke window.wd.onWebPageChange()

Comment: @Ryan already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need define wd:

```
var wd = new WD[name of clase]();
```

in A.js, B.js or Html.